# creating unordered_set with lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, hash, lambda, unordered-set

How can I make `unordered_set` with lambda? (I know how to make it with user defined hash struct and `operator==`)

My current code is :

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <functional>

struct Point
{
    float x;
    float y;
    Point() : x(0), y(0) {}
};

int main()
{
    auto hash=[](const Point& pt){
        return (size_t)(pt.x*100 + pt.y);
    };
    auto hashFunc=[&hash](){
        return  std::function<size_t(const Point&)> (hash);
    };
    auto equal=[](const Point& pt1, const Point& pt2){
        return ((pt1.x == pt2.x) && (pt1.y == pt2.y));
    };
    auto equalFunc=[&equal](){
        return std::function<size_t(const Point&,const Point&)> (equal);
    };
    using PointHash=std::unordered_set<Point,decltype(hashFunc),decltype(equalFunc)>;

    PointHash Test(10,hashFunc,equalFunc);

    return 0;
}
```

It give me few! number of errors ([live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4e4837eab46227f)):

Note that I make a lambda for returning `std::function`  (`equalFunc`,`hashFunc`)  because it seems that in `unordered_set` some functions are trying to copy return type of that lambdas !

Also it's weird that gcc 4.8 compile that code fine ! ( [live](https://ideone.com/LEixBc) )

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no need for the `std::function` abstraction in your code. Just obtain the lambda types directly via `decltype` for `unordered_set`'s template arguments

```
auto hash=[](const Point& pt){
    return (size_t)(pt.x*100 + pt.y);
};

auto equal=[](const Point& pt1, const Point& pt2){
    return ((pt1.x == pt2.x) && (pt1.y == pt2.y));
};

using PointHash = std::unordered_set<Point, decltype(hash), decltype(equal)>;

PointHash Test(10, hash, equal);
```

---

And in places where you're simply performing element-wise comparison of two structs, I find it easier to use `std::tie` instead

```
auto equal=[](const Point& pt1, const Point& pt2){
    return std::tie(pt1.x, pt1.y) == std::tie(pt2.x, pt2.y);
};
```

---

The above code compiles on both gcc and clang, but not on VS2013 because of [this bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/727957/vc11-beta-compiler-fails-to-compile-lambda-key-comparer-for-maps-and-sets). The VS standard library implementation tries to default construct the lambda type somewhere, which is going to fail because the default constructor is deleted. `std::function` can be used as a workaround for VS2013, but I'd stick to defining a `struct` with an overloaded `operator()` instead.

Comment: I don't know why but it's not working in visual studio 2013 . maybe bad implementation of STL ?!

Comment: Be very careful about putting something like this in a header.  Each translation unit which uses that header will generate different lambda types and can very easily lead to an ODR (One Definition Rule) violation or weird incompatibility.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <functional>

struct Point
{
    float x;
    float y;
    Point() : x(0), y(0) {}
};

int main()
{
    auto hash = [](const Point& pt){
        return (size_t)(pt.x*100 + pt.y);
    };

    using hashFunc = std::function<size_t(const Point&)>;

    auto equal = [](const Point& pt1, const Point& pt2){
        return ((pt1.x == pt2.x) && (pt1.y == pt2.y));
    };

    using equalFunc = std::function<size_t(const Point&,const Point&)>;

    using PointHash = std::unordered_set<Point,hashFunc,equalFunc>;

    PointHash Test(10, hash, equal);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `hashFunc` and `equalFunc` after all, just use the lambdas:

```
auto hash = [](const Point& pt){ return (size_t)(pt.x*100 + pt.y); };

auto equal = [](const Point& pt1, const Point& pt2) {return ((pt1.x == pt2.x) && (pt1.y == pt2.y)); };

using PointHash=std::unordered_set<Point,decltype(hash),decltype(equal)>;
PointHash Test(10,hash,equal);
```

[<kbd>**LIVE DEMO**</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/39f3fedee2238ad6)

Comment: I tried that before asking in visual studio 2013 it does not compile !

Answer (score 1):

This won't compile `hashFunc` and `equalFunc` are *capturing* lambdas. Lambdas with capture-clauses do not have an implicit conversion to pointer-to-function type. As you can see from the other answers, you need some way of getting rid of the capture-clauses, which is as simple as using `hash` and `equal` directly.

[It seems that VS can't compile the new code](http://rextester.com/XZHJP95420). Alternatively, you can use free functions instead of lambdas and replacing `decltype(...)` with aliases of function pointer types:

```
std::size_t hash(const Point& pt)
{
    return pt.x * 100 + pt.y;
}

bool equal(const Point& pt1, const Point& pt2)
{
    return ((pt1.x == pt2.x) && (pt1.y == pt2.y));
}

int main()
{
    using hash_type = std::size_t (*)(const Point&);
    using equal_type = bool (*)(const Point&, const Point&);
    using PointHash = std::unordered_set<Point, hash_type, equal_type>;

    PointHash Test(10, hash, equal);
}
```